# Py2neo (V4) - AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'find_one'

Tags: python, flask, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to update the neo4j-flask application to Py2Neo V4 and i could not find how the "find_one" function has been replaced. (Nicole White used Py2Neo V2)

- https://nicolewhite.github.io/neo4j-flask/
- https://github.com/nicolewhite/neo4j-flask
- https://neo4j.com/blog/building-python-web-application-using-flask-neo4j/

My setup:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- Python 3.6.5
- Neo4j Server version: 3.4.6 (community)

Requirements.txt (the rest of the code is from github repository by Nicole White):

```
atomicwrites==1.2.0
attrs==18.1.0
backcall==0.1.0
bcrypt==3.1.4
certifi==2018.8.24
cffi==1.11.5
click==6.7
colorama==0.3.9
decorator==4.3.0
Flask==1.0.2
ipykernel==4.8.2
ipython==6.5.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
itsdangerous==0.24
jedi==0.12.1
Jinja2==2.10
jupyter-client==5.2.3
jupyter-console==5.2.0
jupyter-core==4.4.0
MarkupSafe==1.0
more-itertools==4.3.0
neo4j-driver==1.6.1
neotime==1.0.0
parso==0.3.1
passlib==1.7.1
pexpect==4.6.0
pickleshare==0.7.4
pkg-resources==0.0.0
pluggy==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==1.0.15
ptyprocess==0.6.0
py==1.6.0
py2neo==4.1.0
pycparser==2.18
Pygments==2.2.0
pytest==3.7.3
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
pyzmq==17.1.2
simplegeneric==0.8.1
six==1.11.0
tornado==5.1
traitlets==4.3.2
urllib3==1.22
wcwidth==0.1.7
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Error i received when register user:

> AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'find_one'
>
> "The User.find() method uses py2neo’s Graph.find_one() method to find
>   a node in the database with label :User and the given username,
>   returning a py2neo.Node object. "

In Py2Neo V3 the function `find_one` -> https://py2neo.org/v3/database.html?highlight=find#py2neo.database.Graph.find_one is available.

In Py2Neo V4 https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html there is not find function anymore.

Someone got an idea on how to solve it in V4 or is downgrading here the way to go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

py2neo v4 has a `first` function that can be used with a `NodeMatcher`. See: https://py2neo.org/v4/matching.html#py2neo.matching.NodeMatch.first

That said... v4 has introduced GraphObjects which (so far at least) I've found pretty neat.

In the linked github example Users are created with:

```
user = Node('User', username=self.username, password=bcrypt.encrypt(password))
graph.create(user)
```

and found with

```
user = graph.find_one('User', 'username', self.username)
```

In py2neo v4 I would do this with

```
class User(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = "username"

    username = Property()
    password = Property()

 lukas = User()
 lukas.username = "lukasott"
 lukas.password = bcrypt.encrypt('somepassword')
 graph.push(lukas)
```

and

```
user = User.match(graph, "lukasott").first()
```

The `first` function, as I understand it, provides the same guarantees that `find_one`, as quoted from the v3 docs "and does not fail if more than one matching node is found."

Comment: My open point here is:     class User(GraphObject):
NameError: name 'GraphObject' is not defined -> Thought i could do from py2neo import GraphObject

Comment: Ok solved with: from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property, Label

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me instead. reference the link below

```py
def find(self):
        user = graph.nodes.match("User", self.username).first()
        return user
```

https://py2neo.org/v5/_modules/py2neo/database.html

Comment: yes thanks for the update in V5 they improved a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another simpler way to solve this would be to replace `find_one` with the below:

```
from py2neo import Graph, NodeMatcher
matcher = NodeMatcher(graph)

user = matcher.match('user', name='name').first()
```

Comment: So this is a replacement for v3 syntax:    user = graph.find_one("user", "name", "John")  Thanks! works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Building on the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52058563), here is a minimal example showing the use of `self.match().first()` instead of `find_one()`. 
The attributes are set with `Property()` to provide an accessor to the property of the underlying node. (Documentation here: https://py2neo.org/v4/ogm.html#py2neo.ogm.Property)

```py
from py2neo import Graph, Node
from passlib.hash import bcrypt

from py2neo.ogm import GraphObject, Property

graph = Graph()


class User(GraphObject):
    __primarykey__ = 'username'

    username = Property()
    password = Property()

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def find(self):
        user = self.match(graph, self.username).first()
        return user

    def register(self, password):
        if not self.find():
            user = Node('User', username=self.username, password=bcrypt.encrypt(password))
            graph.create(user)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```